# Adding weather widget powerline

Tags: vim, macvim, vim-powerline

I'm trying to enable weather widget for powerline but with no success. I added this code

```
{
    "name": "weather",
    "priority": 50,
    "args": {
        "unit": "F",
        "location_query": "oslo, norway"
    }
}
```

at the end of my theme file. When I start MacVim I get an error

```
Error detected while processing VimEnter Auto commands for "*":
2014-01-30 14:13:11,122:ERROR:vim:segment_generator:Failed to generate segment from {u'priority': 50, u'args': {u'location_query': u'oslo, norway', u'u
nit': u'F'}, u'name': u'weather'}: 'module' object has no attribute 'weather'
```

I've read powerline documentation but I'm still confused. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Vim is not an operating system; you're confusing it with the _other_ editor, which is everything but a kitchen sink.

Comment: @Ingo Karkat ??? Did I say vim is an operating system????

Comment: When you start adding weather information into your statusline, it'll soon resemble one... How's that related to text editing? Do you code outside?! (And please forgive me my feeble attempts at an inside joke, which you obviously failed to get.)

Comment: As meteorologist this feature is important for me. I'm using vim for writing a different kind of articles.

Comment: As a meteorologist, you certainly have better ways to know what the weather is. As a non-meteorologist, I have a window. Also, powerline issues should be discussed on powerline's issue tracker.

Answer (score 3):

Here is how I configured weather for the Shell.  I don't think it is possible with VI as it is not listed in the available segment

https://powerline.readthedocs.org/en/latest/configuration/segments/vim.html

Create the following folder tree:

```
    ~/.config/powerline/config.json
    ~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/netsamir.json
    ~/.config/powerline/colorschemes/shell/netsamir.json
```

**~/.config/powerline/config.json**

```
{
    "common": {
        "term_truecolor": false
    },
    "ext": {
      "shell": {
            "theme": "netsamir",
            "colorscheme": "netsamir"
        },            
    }
}
```

**~/.config/powerline/themes/shell/netsamir.json**

```
{
    "segments": {
        "above": [
            {
                "left": [
                   {
                        "function":  "powerline.segments.common.wthr.weather",
                        "args": {
                            "unit": "C"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "user",
                        "function": "powerline.segments.common.env.user",
                        "priority": 30
                    },
                    {
                        "function": "powerline.segments.common.vcs.branch",
                        "args": {
                            "status_colors": true,
                            "ignore_statuses": ["U"]
                         }
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "cwd",
                        "function": "powerline.segments.common.env.cwd"
                    }
                ]
            }
         ],
        "left": [
            {
                "type": "string",
                "contents": ">",
                "highlight_groups": ["promptline"],
                "draw_soft_divider": false
            },
            {
                "type": "string",
                "contents": "",
                 "highlight_groups": ["blank"],
                "draw_hard_divider": false
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

**~/.config/powerline/colorschemes/shell/netsamir.json**

```
{
    "name": "netsamir",
    "groups": {
        "information:additional":    { "fg": "gray9", "bg": "gray4", "attrs": [] },
        "information:regular":       { "fg": "gray10", "bg": "gray4", "attrs": [] },
        "information:highlighted":   { "fg": "white", "bg": "gray4", "attrs": ["bold"] },
        "information:priority":      { "fg": "brightyellow", "bg": "mediumorange", "attrs": [] },
        "hostname":                  { "fg": "black", "bg": "gray10", "attrs": ["bold"] },
        "background:divider":        "information:additional",
        "weather":                   { "fg": "gray9", "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
        "user":                      { "fg": "brightcyan", "bg": "darkestblue", "attrs": ["bold"] },
        "branch":                    { "fg": "gray9", "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
        "branch_dirty":              { "fg": "black", "bg": "orangered", "attrs": [] },
        "branch_clean":              { "fg": "gray9", "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
        "branch:divider":            { "fg": "gray7", "bg": "gray2", "attrs": [] },
        "cwd":                       "information:additional",
        "cwd:current_folder":        "information:highlighted",
        "cwd:divider":               { "fg": "gray7", "bg": "gray4", "attrs": [] },
        "promptline": { "fg": "white", "bg": "darkestblue", "attrs": ["bold"] },
        "blank": { "fg": "black", "bg": "black", "attrs": [] }
    }
}
```